# Trigger addin from another addin - different host programs

Tags: add-in, autocad, autodesk, revit

I have an addin in Autodesk Revit that automates some stuff for me, e.g. it exports a file to a given location (.dwg file).
within Autocad i have an addin as well, that needs to process the specific export.

I know how to write/code addins for both software independent, but i am wondering if it is possible to send a command  from one addin to the other, where both addins live in an different software program. So in my case, i want to sent an command from my Revit addin, to my Autocad addin.

Is it possible to make some kind of listener of trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways to do that, and they have nothing whatsoever to do with the Revit or AutoCAD APIs.

One traditional way to send messages between different applications is to use a so-called pipe: [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), [anonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe).

There are many other methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into TECHSOFT3D's [RealDWG](https://www.techsoft3d.com/products/realdwg/) library?  It is the only tool that I know of that will allow you to read/write dwg files from outside of AutoCAD.  It has the exact same functions as the AutoCAD API excluding any user interface or printing functionality.  I use it as part of an all-in-one Revit add-in so that I can do post-processing of a dwg file after it has been generated using the Revit API export functionality.  That way I don't need to have a separate AutoCAD add-in and I don't have to worry about handling different versions of both Revit AND AutoCAD.  Note, however, that [RealDWG](https://www.techsoft3d.com/products/realdwg/) is not free.